# Cannot install android apk to emulator from command prompt

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools>adb install D:\HelloFacebookSample.apk
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools>
```

This is my error please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adb.exe` is not in your system's path, so `cmd` cannot find it.

It is located in `\...\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk\`**platform-tools**>, not in `\...\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\`**tools**

Answer (score 0):

You're in the wrong directory.  There is no adb in that one, its in platform-tools, not tools.  Also, you may want to add that directory to your path environment variable, so you can use it from any directory.